# How to fix error with Sum of close pairs on the list

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I want to sum each list of 2 pairs close and return a new list where each organ is the sum of the next 2 pairs.

i have this code:

what i do wrong?

```
(define (add-consecutives lst)
(if (null? (Cdr lst)
                 Null
                (cons
                      (+ (car lst) (cadr lst)
                       (add-consecutives (cadr lst )))))))

(add-consecutives (list 1 2 3 4))
```

when i run it i get bad syntax.
what i do wrong?

thank's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of syntax problems. For starters, you forgot to close the parentheses for the `null?` call, and also the parentheses in the recursive step are misplaced. All this can be avoided by properly indenting the code and using an IDE with syntax highlighting.

There are deeper problems, too. The way you're advancing the recursion is incorrect (you need to move to the rest of the list) and you should handle the edge cases when there are 0, 1, 2 elements left. This should address all the issues:

```
(define (add-consecutives lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) null)
        ((null? (cdr lst))  (list (car lst)))
        ((null? (cddr lst)) (list (+ (car lst) (cadr lst))))
        (else (cons (+ (car lst) (cadr lst))
                    (add-consecutives (cdr lst))))))
```

Let's try some tests:

```
(add-consecutives (list))
=> '()
(add-consecutives (list 1))
=> '(1)
(add-consecutives (list 1 2))
=> '(3)
(add-consecutives (list 1 2 3))
=> '(3 5)
(add-consecutives (list 1 2 3 4))
=> '(3 5 7)
```

Comment: thank's it's working but i need for list 1 2 3 4 this return me [3 5 7] i try to change in your code (cddr to cadr ) ...(add-consecutives (cadr lst))))))

Comment: @liran I don't understand your comment, for `'(1 2 3 4)` my answer is returning `'(3 7)`, why were you expecting  `'(3 5 7)`? how do you reach that result?

Comment: for example: for (list 1 2 3 4) i need to calculate (1+2) and (2+3) and (3+4) and get new list -> [3 5 7]

Comment: I understand now! and what about this list: `'(1 2 3)`, what's the expected result?

Comment: for '(1 2 3) returns: new list -> [3 5]

Comment: @liran ok, I updated my answer. It's a bit long to properly handle the edge cases - single element list, empty list.